# tkinter - Expanding a Listbox inside a Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

As the title says, I'm trying to make a Listbox object occupy all space that is inside a Notebook pane.

Here is a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image: Part of a GUI I'm working on. As you can see, the space left on the right is far from appealing]

What I want to do is to expand the Listbox to occupy all the space that's on the right. I know that if I say `listbox['width']  = value` to a high enough value, the Notebook panes' titles will not bug this. However I am looking for alternative ways to do this, either resorting to `grid()` (what I'm using in this project) or `pack()`.

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using pack, do it like this:

```
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
listbox.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

If you're using grid, make sure you call `columnconfigure` on column 0 and give it a weight that is greater than zero, which will cause it to expand and fill up any extra space in the container.

```
containing_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: That solved it. In fact I was using `grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` but I forgot it applied to the parent frame, not to the widget. This being said, I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `sticky = E` for the scroll bar `grid` and then try `sticky = EW` in the list box.

If that does not work, trying playing around with the column spans of the widgets.

Comment: If I removed sticky=(N,S) then the scrollbar wouldn't stretch to the upper and lower boundaries. sticky = E doesn't work.